# Cannot connect to google cloud external static ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, firewall

I've followed a Google Cloud Platform tutorial to create a VM instance. I've added an external static ip, making sure I allow http/https traffic. Now when I try to access the external ip in my browser, I get the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The instance is running since I can get into it by SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would SSH into the VM first and do a curl localhost to check if webserver is running, that is getting a 200 response. If everything is fine there then move on to check your firewall settings.

Comment: Thanks Dany. Webserver was not running because there was an error in google app.py file (tensorflow.compat.v1 module not found). I upgraded to tensorflow 2 and it's ok now.